# Populating META-INF/context.xml

Tags: deployment, build, webserver, tomcat7, maven-3

I am using maven as my build and dependency management tool. I am successful in copying the context.xml in META-INF folder through maven build.

What I want here is to dynamically populate the docBase and path attributes in the  tag of the context.xml file.

Please let me know if there is any way of doing it. Most preferable would be putting the war's finalName in the docBase attribute.

I am not sure if it is feasible or not. Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

This is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    
instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> 
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>myproj</groupId>
<artifactId>myproj</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <file>
                <exists>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <toolsjar>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</toolsjar>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>mac-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <file>
                <exists>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <toolsjar>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</toolsjar>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <defaultGoal>clean</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>

                <format>{0,number} ({1,date,MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm 'PDT'})</format>
                <items>
                    <item>buildNumber0</item>
                    <item>timestamp</item>
                </items>
                <shortRevisionLength>5</shortRevisionLength>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources
                        </directory>

                    </resource>
                </webResources>

                <warName>mywar</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
</build>

 </project>
```

Thanks

Comment: The first thing that you show your pom.xml file?